# One folder in TFS doesn't map like all the others - how do I remap this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

In Visual Studio 2012, in my TFS Workspace, I have "Source Control Folder" set to the TFS root "/$". I have the "Local Folder" set to "C:\TFS". In Source Control Explorer, all folders line up with my local machine EXCEPT ONE. For example:

```
TFS_SERVER\FolderA -> C:\TFS\FolderA
TFS_SERVER\FolderB -> C:\TFS\FolderB
TFS_SERVER\FolderC -> C:\TFS\FOO\FolderC       ** Why?
```

I don't know why this maps to a FOO subfolder, and I can't find a way to remap it to go to C:\TFS\FolderC. How can I get this pointed to the right location? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may map the FolderC to C:\TFS\FOO before. Right click FolderC and click **Remove Mapping**, then remap the local folder.

[image]

Comment: I only have the option to Remove Mapping at the root of TFS. None of my nested folders show that option.